# Get DI Context in derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I am wondering how to get hold of my db context in a derived class (.net6 c#)

I have registered my context in Program.cs and on all of my controllers I can simply use this pattern to get the contect (same with services - they are all scoped services in program):

```
MyController(MyContext context)
{
}
```

This allows me to grab the context and work with it.

I have a class called person that is bought in from my db by EF power tools. I also have a class that derives from person like this:

```
public class ExtendedPerson : Person
{
   public ExtendedPerson(Person psn)
   {
      Name = psn.Name;
      Age = psn.age;
   }
  public bool MyBool()
  {
    //Here I need to get my context to do some DB checks
  }
}
```

I tried to add the context to the constructor of ExtendedPerson in the same way as I would with the controller, but when creating an instance of ExtendedPerson I want it to get that context from DI instead of me having to new up a context.

The same could be said for services, all of my services are registered for DI, if I want to use them in this class surely I don't have to do this:

```
var extendedPerson = new ExtendedPerson(person, context, service1, service2);
```

Am I looking at this the wrong way somewhere??

Many thanks

Comment: ExtendedPerson sounds like a DTO type class, a class that should contain data. It probably shouldn't be reaching out to a database itself. What are you trying to reach out to the database for? To validate that the ExtendedPerson is valid? In that case, a separate class to perform validation, perhaps called ExtendedPersonValidator, might be a good idea. That class can take in a DbContext via constructor injection, and have methods available for validating an ExtendedPerson.

Comment: extended person would have methods on it that we can use to check something about a person that is not available in the main person class. So, for example we might have a method in that extended class called HasCharges(). We would then need to apply business logic to check if that person has charges, part of that business logic would need to interrogate the db.

Comment: Why mix those concerns directly into a type that is managed by Entity Framework? Move that to a separate class: you'll thank yourself later. Then, entity framework can continue to work with your data types easily, and your business logic class can take direct dependencies on the DbContext as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Like mason already said, all the business logic that handles the Person entity, ideally belongs to the PersonService class with its own interface. In that service, all the dependencies can be resolved with constructor injection without a problem.

On the other hand, sometimes some simple calculated properties on EF entities come in handy. For those cases, you can create a partial class - that way, if you have autogenerated EF entity classes (DB first approach), scaffolding the DB won't overwrite your logic.